# Youtube Gaming live streaming

Tags: youtube, http-live-streaming

Can anyone shed some light on the live streaming stack Youtube Gaming uses to achieve that crazy framerate? (60fps)

Looks to me like HLS, but better. Receives chunks of binary data every ~3 seconds, one chunk is ~200kb.

What do you think the source type is?
[image]

PS: I have implemented live streaming through HTTP using https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg - sending binary data through websockets to the browser. While it works cross-vendor and achieves ~20fps it's nowhere near and doesn't have sound.

Comment: They do also use QUIC (SPDY over UDP) which helps to eliminate handshakes and ignore shaper (TCP congestion window)

Comment: Interesting, seems this is only supported by google servers so far.

Comment: wait until Nginx support HTTP/2 (later this year)

Answer (score 5):

YouTube provides multiple formats, depending on the client device/browser.

The streams that look like `HLS` are using `DASH` (see [Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) and [Adaptive Bitrate Streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming)). 
Look for network requests for the manifest files which have the `video/vnd.mpeg.dash.mpd` or `application/dash+xml` MIME types.

They use separate streams for audio and video synchronized on the player.

For `60fps` it seems to support both `MPEG-DASH` (`H.264/AVC` in `MP4` container with `AAC` audio in `M4A`) and `WebM DASH` (`VP9` with `Opus` in `WebM`). WebM is royalty-free, MPEG is paid.

Here's the output from `youtube-dl --list-formats` for a radom stream:

```
format code  extension  resolution note
249          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @ 50k
250          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @ 70k
251          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @160k
171          webm       audio only DASH audio  113k , audio@128k (44100Hz), 2.27MiB
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  129k , m4a_dash container, aac  @128k (44100Hz), 2.81MiB
141          m4a        audio only DASH audio  255k , m4a_dash container, aac  @256k (44100Hz), 5.59MiB
247          webm       720p       DASH video , video only
136          mp4        720p       DASH video , video only
248          webm       1080p      DASH video , video only
137          mp4        1080p      DASH video , video only
160          mp4        256x144    DASH video  110k , 15fps, video only, 2.28MiB
278          webm       256x144    DASH video  190k , webm container, VP9, 15fps, video only, 2.11MiB
242          webm       426x240    DASH video  227k , 30fps, video only, 3.58MiB
133          mp4        426x240    DASH video  250k , 30fps, video only, 5.18MiB
243          webm       640x360    DASH video  403k , 30fps, video only, 6.69MiB
134          mp4        640x360    DASH video  617k , 30fps, video only, 8.97MiB
244          webm       854x480    DASH video  864k , 30fps, video only, 12.89MiB
135          mp4        854x480    DASH video 1115k , 30fps, video only, 17.25MiB
302          webm       1280x720   DASH video 2933k , VP9, 60fps, video only, 43.81MiB
298          mp4        1280x720   DASH video 3373k , h264, 60fps, video only, 54.42MiB
303          webm       1920x1080  DASH video 5055k , VP9, 60fps, video only, 80.96MiB
299          mp4        1920x1080  DASH video 5584k , h264, 60fps, video only, 96.97MiB
13           3gp        unknown    
17           3gp        176x144    
36           3gp        320x240    
5            flv        400x240    
43           webm       640x360    
18           mp4        640x360    
22           mp4        1280x720   (best)
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the info. Sad thing that on Firefox it still defaults to Flash.